# Do "wuseln" or "wuselig sein" have a negative connotation?

Tags: meaning, verb

In recent years there is an increased usage of "wuseln" or "wuselig sein" when it comes to describing bustling people or a very lively situation.

Is this expression used in a positive sense or does it have a negative connotation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I heard it recently during the World Cup when the [German team said](http://www.zdf.de/ZDFmediathek/beitrag/video/1381544/Schmidt-Japanerinnen-sind-wuselig#/beitrag/video/1381544/Schmidt-Japanerinnen-sind-ballsicher) that the Japanese women are so "wuselig". This was meant positively, I think, as a tribute to their playing style and that it would not be easy to beat them. And we all know what happened.

In other cases, I never heard it with a real negative connotation. Sometimes people say it when there are too many people in one place, like a *Volksfest* ("das ist mir zu wuselig"). But I think it also implies that it is fine for other people who like to "wusel". If you're on a high tower, you may hear that the people on the ground "wuseln wie die Ameisen". Not negative either, and I've also heard it for several plushy animals living in large groups, where it stands for cuteness rather than anything else.

The word has been used for almost two decades now in the video game field. Typical German build-up strategy games had a "Wuselfaktor", with the canonical example being the old Settlers games. This was also rather positive, as it meant that the game has come to life and was not *leblos*, and it was not only fun to play, but also to *just watch them doing their things* because it's cute. A recent example for this is Anno 1404 (known as *Dawn of Discovery* in the English-speaking world, I think), which also has a great Wuselfaktor.

Comment: "The Settlers" is what came to my mind immediately as well :)

Comment: I'd like to add that the term is a kind of belittlement. Most of time I've heard it being used, it was for beings (humans and animals) that are both small and fast. It's often used to describe kids that can't stand still.

Comment: @DarkDust: Agree with kids that can't stand still - but I think wuseln also implies that there are several (or rather a lot) of beings to "wusel".

Comment: "not leblos" = "not lifeless"

Answer (score 1):

*Wuseln* beschreibt eine Bewegungsform. Wie man diese bewertet hängt vom Sprecher, vom Hörer, der Betonung und vom Kontext ab. Das hat eigentlich gar nichts mit dem Wort wuseln zu tun, sondern gilt für jedes Wort.

Selbst ein Wort wie *diskriminieren*, welches viele Leute nur in Zusammenhängen gebrauchen, in denen sie die Diskriminierung kritisieren würden, ist nicht mit einer negativen Bewertung verbunden.

Wenn man die Illusion nährt, dass Wörter derartige Konnotationen tragen, unterstellt man damit einen uniformen Blick auf die Welt, der einer pluralistischen Gesellschaft mit unterschiedlichen Werten, Geschmäckern und Perspektiven nicht entspricht.

Wenn ein Fußballtrainer erklärt, dass die ausgeprägte Fähigkeit eines Spielers darin besteht, dass er konsequent nach hinten arbeitet, dann kann ich dieser Einschätzung zustimmen, aber aus genau diesem Grund den Spieler ablehnen. Es liegt aber nicht am sprachlichen Ausdruck - der beschreibt den Sachverhalt treffend.

Eine Zeitlang wurde im Fussball eine Spielweise kritisiert, die als *Klein-Klein* bezeichnet wurde. In der Tat wird eine ähnliche Spielweise, die gelobt werden soll, *gepflegtes Kurzpassspiel* genannt, oder neutral schlicht *Kurzpassspiel*. Es ist aber leicht über die Stimme, sofern es mündliche Rede ist, oder den Kontext *Klein-Klein* positiv zu besetzen.

Man könnte nun argumentieren, dass Worte aber häufig so oder so eingesetzt werden. Nur kann man sich an der Häufigkeit nicht orientieren, um zu erfassen, was der Sprecher meint. Auch wenn *nach hinten arbeiten* von vielen lobend verwendet wird, muss man im Einzelfall die Betonung, den Zusammenhang und eventuell Wissen über den Sprecher und Adressaten verwenden, um den Satz zu interpretieren.

Comment: eigentlich gute Thesen; aber irgendwie auch ein bisschen wenig Text über das eigentliche Wort *wuseln*. Wüsste jetzt aber auch (noch) nicht wirklich, wie ich's besser machen würde. ;)

Comment: @klyonrad: Wenn ich sage, dass Wörter nicht aus sich heraus negativ o. positiv sind, dann wäre es doch inkonsequent das Wort selbst dann doch zu analysieren.